# static variables in class library used by two applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, caching, static

I have an issue which I came across today which I am hoping someone may be able to to answer. I may be missing something and I don't have the code in front of me right now so am remembering this from memory.

I have a .NET MVC web application which has two layers, a UI layer and a service layer (WCF service). The UI layer has a service reference to the WCF service.

The UI layer caches some data into static variables on Application_Start in the global.asax file. These static variables are within a class in a referenced shared class library.

My WCF layer also references this class library and the static variables mentioned.

Both these layers are installed on separate servers so under their own IIS instance.

Is there any way that my WCF service could access the data in the static variables populated by the UI layer? I would have thought the service layer has its own instance of the referenced assembly and therefore the variables within it belong to itself only?

The reason I ask is this. There used to be a global.asax file on the service layer also which I recently removed which also used to populate the static variables in the shared library.

On removing this global.asax file completely from the service layer, it was still able to access the data populated by the UI layer (at least i think it was). The application would still function for a certain period of time, when left inactive (i think) these variables in the service layer became NULL and I was getting null reference exceptions.

The only way to populate the variables again was to restart the UI layer application pool. The application then worked again for some time and the repeated.

I am unsure if what I am explaining is possible in which case I am missing something or if anyone knows why this might be happening?

Comment: Could you shorten your text a bit? I find it a bit unclear. Btw. if you want to see what accesses something else, just use a debugger and step into the code and look if this is true. Usually I would say that two different applications definitely cannot access static variables of each other, but I'm not even sure what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are only static within an AppDomain.  When IIS shuts down the App Pool (due to inactivity, etc.) those static values will be gone.

I would reference the static variables in your WCF project and then add services for the WCF layer to use to get those static values.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I agree with your comment about what the solution should be. However what I am trying to understand is why I am seeing this behaviour with the current setup mentioned. Thinking about it, I think the static variables on application start of the ui layer actually get populated by calling a method in the wcf layer anyway. Does that help with the issue?

Comment: Not completely clear what you're trying to do - but bottom line is the static variables will go away when the process shuts down.  For a WCF service the process is the AppPool.

Comment: What I am really trying to understand is how my wcf layer can access the static variables which have been set by the ui layer which is on a different server.

Comment: I can't tell you why - it shouldn't be possible.  If you want to pass the values back to the WCF service add methods to accept them from the UI layer.